# Can one domain have multiple nameservers?

Tags: nameserver

Can I have 2 sets of name servers for one domain? i.e.  If the sub-domain is not found one set of name servers then it checks the next set of name servers?

Comment: Could you explain your question a little bit more? Second sentence is not clear... In regards to the `Can I have 2 sets of name servers for one domain` - a domain can have multiple DNS servers. Look at the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Name_servers) about it.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of, but depending on your needs it may or may not work the way you want it to.

The purpose of having more than one nameserver on a domain is redundancy, if there are multiple then each nameserver would be expected to contain the same records as its peers.

That being said, you can create an NS (or multiple NS records) so that a subdomain and its children would be handled by another set of nameservers.

It would look something like the following...

Primary nameserver(s) for the domain (let's call them ns1.foo.com and ns2.foo.com, and let's say the domain in question is example.com):

```
.        A        1.2.3.4
www      A        1.2.3.4
sub      NS       ns1.bar.com
sub      NS       ns2.bar.com
(other records)
```

Sub nameservers (ns1.bar.com and ns2.bar.com):

```
.        A        4.5.6.7
www      A        4.5.6.7
(other records)
```

All name resolution requests will initially go to ns1.foo.com or ns2.foo.com. If the name to be resolved is `sub.example.com` or `*.sub.example.com` then the first set of name servers (`ns*.foo.com`) send the request on to `ns*.bar.com` for resolution.